# Checking if VPN connection was successful after connection through applescript

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, vpn

I have a script that will connect you to a VPN, but I don't have a way to tell if the user has been connected successfully. When the script runs, it will prompt the user to enter their password. But if the user hits cancel, my script still thinks that they got connected.

```
    tell application "System Events"
        tell current location of network preferences
            set VPNService to service "MyVPN"
            if exists VPNService then
                try
                    connect VPNService
                    set VPNFailed to "false"
                on error
                    set VPNFailed to "true"
                end try
            else


            end if

        end tell
    end tell
            delay 11

    if VPNFailed is "true" then
        set image1 to current application's NSImage's imageNamed_("NSStatusUnavailable")
        UIVPNStatus's setImage_(image1)
        display dialog "Server is down, please try again later." buttons {"OK"}
        else
        set image1 to current application's NSImage's imageNamed_("NSStatusAvailable")
        UIVPNStatus's setImage_(image1)
        display notification "" with title "Connection Successful!" subtitle "You may now browse the internet privatley and securley"
        set image2 to current application's NSImage's imageNamed_("VPNLocked.png")
        UIVPNLock's setImage_(image2)
    end if
    else
    display dialog "Cannot connect to server." buttons {"OK"} with icon 2
    set volume 7
    beep
    tell VPNProgress to stopAnimation_(sender)
   end if

    tell VPNProgress to stopAnimation_(sender)
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to address it is to establish a timer that keeps pinging the connection status until it either returns true, or times out.  Here's a stab at it (I simplified your code to cut to the meat of the issue). Note this code assumes you're using Mac's built-in VPN.

```
set myVPNServiceName to "Your VPN connection name" --update with real name
set timer to 20 -- update to whatever time (in seconds) you feel is acceptable
set isVPNConnected to false

tell application "System Events"

    tell current location of network preferences

        set VPNService to null
        set vpnConnectionInProgress to false

        -- Try to connect to VPN service
        try
            set VPNService to service myVPNServiceName
            connect VPNService
            set vpnConnectionInProgress to true
        end try

        if vpnConnectionInProgress is true then

            -- keep checking until timer expires or connection is confirmed
            repeat while timer > 0 and isVPNConnected is false

                if current configuration of VPNService is connected then
                    set isVPNConnected to true
                end if

                log isVPNConnected

                set timer to timer - 1
                delay 1

            end repeat

        end if

    end tell

end tell

if isVPNConnected is true then
    display notification "" with title "Connection Successful!" subtitle "You may now browse the internet privately and securely"
else
    display dialog "Cannot connect to " & myVPNServiceName buttons {"OK"}
end if
```